# Search for a Dataset where a associated Dataset has a specific value using Active-Record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

i am currently trying to do a "complex" search inside my Datasets.
I want to find every Dataset that is associated with a specific tool. 
I tried something like this:

```
Dataset.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM datasets, tools, sectors, products  WHERE datasets.id = sectors.dataset_id AND sectors.product_id = products.id AND products.tool_id = tools.id AND tools.name = '#{toolname}'")
```

This works well. But we want to define scopes for querys, for being able to combine some of them later like: Dataset.find_by_toolname("foo").find_by_sector_name("foo2"). So i defined a scope for this:

```
scope :with_tool_name, ->(toolname) {find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM datasets, tools, sectors, products  WHERE datasets.id = sectors.dataset_id AND sectors.product_id = products.id AND products.tool_id = tools.id AND tools.name = '#{toolname}'")}
```

The Problem here is that this query will return an Array and not an ActiveRecord-Relation so that i a am not able to do another scope-request on the result of the first.

So how can i fetch for Data where an attribute of some associated model has a specific value .. and then apply another scope on this ?

Here is what the Data-Model looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the activerecord-method joins(). And the result of every join can be mixed together with the method merge(). Here a small example to get all datasets for one tool_id.

`Dataset.joins(:sectors).merge(Sector.joins(:product)).merge(Product.joins(:tool).where(:tool_id => 1))`